# How to su and run python script in shell?

Tags: python, shell, exit

What I want to do is let my shell script stop when my python script, which is run by shell, exit unnormally. However I have to su to the ossadm to run the python script, how can I get the correct exit code when I su

Here is my code:

```
# shell script
    su ossadm <<EOF
    . /opt/oss/manager/bin/engr_profile.sh # which only can be executed by ossadm
    python ${SRC_DIR}/main.pyc
    echo $?
    if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
        echo "success"
    else
        echo "failure: $?"
    fi
EOF

# main.py
def main():
    sys.exit(1) # for testing
```

then run the script, it always prints **"0"** and **"suceess"**, or change the sequence:

```
    su ossadm <<EOF
    . /opt/oss/manager/bin/engr_profile.sh # which only can be executed by ossadm
    python ${SRC_DIR}/main.pyc
EOF
    echo $?
    if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
        echo "success"
    else
        echo "failure: $?"
    fi

# main.py
def main():
    sys.exit(1) # for testing
```

This one will give me weirder "1" and "success".

Could this kind of processing could be done in shell script?

Comment: For last example, `echo $?` succeeds, so on the next line `$?` is 0.

Comment: Why are you running `main.pyc` directly? The speedup (especially in this case) is negligible, and it won't reflect any changes you may make to `main.py` without explicitly recompiling it.

Comment: @chepner to be honest, it's because my company want me to do so..to keep users from reaching the source code SO directly, althrough we all know it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on you shell  you can try something like this.

```
su ossadm -c '. /opt/oss/manager/bin/engr_profile.sh; 
python "${SRC_DIR}"/main.pyc'  && echo "sucess" || echo "failure"
```

Here `-c` flag will run commands as `ossadm`.

Where `&&`  is logical and which runs code block after it if previous command is successful .
`||` is logical or and code block after  this runs if previous command fails.

To make matter more clear, you can put code for success and failure in different files

```
su ossadm -c '. /opt/oss/manager/bin/engr_profile.sh;
python "${SRC_DIR}"/main.pyc' && /tmp/b.sh || /tmp/c.sh
```

Where `b.sh` runs  when su command (in your case python script) exits with code ‘0’
And.  `c.sh` runs  when su command (in your case python script) exits with code ‘1’

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the `EOF` token. Otherwise, variables in the here-doc are expanded by the original shell, so `$?` contains the exit status of the last command you ran before `su`.

```
# shell script
su ossadm <<'EOF'
    . /opt/oss/manager/bin/engr_profile.sh # which only can be executed by ossadm
    python "${SRC_DIR}"/main.pyc
    status=$?
    echo $status
    if [[ $status = 0 ]]; then
        echo "success"
    else
        echo "failure: $?"
    fi
EOF
```

If `SRC_DIR` is a variable set in the original shell, make sure you export it so that it will be inherited by the shell run by `su`, since it will no longer be expanded by the original shell. But if it's set by `engr_profile.sh`, quoting the token will make it expand correctly.

The reason you're getting `1` and `success` in your second version is because the `echo` statement sets `$?` based on its own success. If you want to print an exit status and also test it, you need to save it in another variable, as I've done with the `status` variable above.

Comment: It might be the intention to expand `$SRC_DIR` before running the script, though, so quoting `EOF` may not be the right answer.

Comment: Then it needs to be exported. I've added info about that.